# Clean up static resource in a test method in Xunit UnitTests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am using Xunit for unit testing in C# environment.
I have some static resources such static cache that some of the methods I test are dependent on that static cache.
In my unit tests, I modify this static cache as I want and check if the behavior of my method has changed accordingly. At the end of the test, I clean up my static cache so the other unit tests won't be effected.

The problems starts when I run all of my unit tests in parallel.
Multiple units tests that are depended on the static cache run simultaneously, what make the test to be unstable (one time they run successfully and the other time they fail).

What can I do to make these specific tests to run synchronously? or any other solution to make the clean up work

Thanks!

Comment: The simple, but probably unhelpful, answer is "don't use static resources". You have discovered one of the key reasons why static mutable state must always be avoided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not thread-safe, tolerant for running in parallel, so when you unit test them in parallel it won't work (which is expected).

There are two possible solutions:

- Don't use static resources
- Don't run your tests in parallel

Comment: The code is Thread safe. The two methods add ad remove simultaneously to the static cache successfully.

Comment: Wikipedia:  A piece of code is thread-safe if it only manipulates shared data structures in a manner that guarantees safe execution by multiple threads at the same time. Looking at your problem, I'd say that's not the case here, since it fails sometimes and sometimes not

Comment: I see. Do you know any workaround? Something like mokcing the static resource or making the tests run in a way the others must wait for the to finish.

Comment: Not running your tests in parallel :-)  If not that, I'd say, go with my first suggestion: don't use static resource (or refactor them so you can mock them in your tests)

Comment: Making the class that holds that static resource to a Singleton would help solve the problem?

Comment: No, because a singleton is still just a front for a static resource. You'd have to really make it a non-static resource (when you're not testing you could inject a static resource into it if you still insist on having it static)